# Bambora Payment Service + React Application integration

Tags: redirect, payment, client-side, bambora

I'm trying to set up a third party payment service with my React application.
https://developer.bambora.com/europe/sdk/web-sdk/checkout-integration

I'm trying to figure out how to send form data onSubmit as an object to pre-populate form fields on the Bambora redirect URL page.

I'm thinking that I have to create a state object, populate it `onSubmit` of the fields, if valid pass it to the `RedirectCheckout()` somehow. I'm not sure how to do that last part.

```js
import { RedirectCheckout } from "@bambora/checkout-sdk-web";

....

new RedirectCheckout("<<YOUR-SESSION-TOKEN-HERE>>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using the checkout link generator from Bambora and creating a hash function using the params they used in their hash function for validation for the link.